# An example of $g$ such that $f(b)-f(a) \le g(|b-a|)^c$ does not imply the differentiability of $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Recall the problem from my [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848168/why-does-fb-fa-le-gb-ac-imply-that-f-is-infinitely-differentiable/) question:

> Let $f,g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be functions such that $g(x)\ge 0,\ g(0)=0$ and $g$ is differentiable at the origin. Suppose for some $c > 1$, 
>   $$f(b)-f(a) \le g(|b-a|)^c$$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

I've been trying to construct a counterexample when the statement fails if the assumption on the differentiability of $g$ is omitted. That is, an example of $f,g$ such that $g$ is only continuous and $f$ is not differentiable at all points of the real line.

Since $g$ is assumed to be non-negative, the first candicate for $g$ is $g(t)=\sqrt t$ - it's continuous at the origin but not differentiable there. But there are so many candidates for $f$ that I don't know how I can choose one so that the inequality is satisfied.

Comment: Please put $g\ge 0$ in the hypotheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A silly (but valid) counterexample would be 
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x=0\\
1 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
It's not even continuous, but satisfies the assumption; and with this it is easy to find examples of $f$ not even continuous themselves.

---

A more interesting one would be to "reverse-engineer" the dependence on $c\geq 1$ to "beat" the use of it in the proof. Namely, set
$$
g(x) = \lvert x\rvert^{1/{c}}, \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}
$$
Then $g$ is continous, and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. However, the assumption
$$
f(b) - f(a) \leq \lvert b-a\rvert, \qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}
$$
leads to continuity ([Lipschitz continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), even) of $f$, but not to its differentiability.

*(You can of course do more fine-tuned things: for instance, with the exponent $\alpha/c$ you can restrict $f$ to be [$\alpha$-Hölder continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).)*

Comment: So I can just take $t\mapsto |t|$ for $f$?

Comment: For the $1/c$, one, yes. @user5579085

Answer (score 1):

With the square root for $g$ you are looking for functions such that:
$$f(b)-f(a) \leq |b-a|^\frac{c}{2}$$
as noted in the comments the condition is equivalent to:
$$|f(b)-f(a)| \leq |b-a|^\frac{c}{2}$$
you obtain for $c <2$ the [Holdër functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) which are not necessarily differentiable, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136445/h%C3%B6lder-continuous-but-not-differentiable-function).

If $c >2 $ you can replace $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ by $g(x)=\sqrt[r]{x}$ for any $r >c$.

Comment: $c>1$, not $c=1$: for $c=3$  for instance your choice still leads to $c/2>1$, and thus $f$ being infinitely differentiable. (Actually, constant). And the condition with absolute values is not "stronger", it is *equivalent*. (Apply the original condition to both $a,b$ and $b,a$ to see it.)

Comment: Good point for the equivalence, for the $c$ it is indeed true that you need to adapt the constant $1/2$ to $c$ but any $|x|^r$ with $r<1/c$ ( in the same spirit as your answer :-))